# Python - Microsoft Access Token Request Error - 400 Bad Request

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, token

I am trying to get access token from access code . but there is a error of 400 Bad Request error

I am using this link to get Access code

in response of this link i am getting the code in query string with return url
code=0.ARAAFJ0TJCzGR0yL3c5x6h1Qz0253KDx4QtFrMHVT2YmlaUQAOw.AgABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrAgDs_wQA9P_v97FhMMeLPwetJQTyqiAGcGH58lwAo6A_ZZolSYosec92P2Jrub9QkWnd9YXe5CkT3TVaqdVS7L1a8HR24Cw0uvavTJLsUO6tWkEoH_R06KnA6C4ZAOJpmBm27DXwFTQ2UWwtUGuYc9aZ7lfOkaSYEsUBXUoA1NLrhOiyXoACciHT2rQrgP59BhjaRYDNuKjJE6JiQx91spNUuklVveyclvPvlZ9rTV6h_gpzsuyC1eEbSA_4dbQaNTOpNF2U3vzzkCo3xgJYmULiDVSGp7K2iub9bNZhbiiexb3XgSV8E04OUvQIKkGlnlnuCItazEt3EkMvCP7FunimfFaFlaf_2ezaMncHYpn4KaoR_R1dI_tesooq71goe3GcmbKFSAKr4WGthlc2OKj6vcHjUmkP9TaGeyros-gR1lpPd-QTdTpVf4Q8_v7rJd8E7SXhMz1k_w1c3Crmt-1owjj6eeLA4pMqch8PPotqffdepAdjg4HX9fPnJV6NNgZP7ofoPCu-j8YikqGBjv11Ynum0tzJr2F4TZa0CIPU1Do97JFWpsjE35XC2DQlY1wTQRFtGNNRu0h81fuweXTdnci1c2utcsZqG87jln3iF9H-JOdZAfi0wGHzwY7Qrv3dFPIbaVyZyit6NCGa7g2TSUwWm7Ci1UQbXRoAkR1mzOucGFCP4WKE2mQfNfgQEiQCkZD9PeXjzm7NkbU9Q7AuYo6-1phMdfiTrruopAVHWbM04sjxJJU0LR4q8zYCbrgfkjBLDhi0SWpVNwzk9Og-02F0DPMh-6vXcVqjDVhVjl1YKOJ6pSY_Yofh97KJNmuj3YpkW3Ve2Pv3FQITZJLCRW0v7xIf7hStCnJQ9Yyi7bLcGcYv2_KTvyMgQS327FEbmDJGVU6cc6Kn

i am using this code to get access token :
[image]

But it is giving : requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: What are the header values in your request? Are you seeing any other error details?

Comment: Could you provide the link from which you are trying to obtain the access code?